# Embed advertisements in a windows application

Tags: c#, windows, embed, ads

I'm developing a free application and would like to make some money by embedding advertisements in it. Initially I had planned to embed ads in a webbrowser control (AdSense, Google Ads) but found that this isn't allowed. Does anybody have experience with this?

The program is coded in C# and will run on PCs not windows mobile

Comment: I've never done this personally, so I'm just curious...  Why isn't this allowed?  I mean, I hate adware, so I wouldn't do it myself without offering a version without it, but what exactly makes this disallowed?

Comment: If you are going to embed adversiting, via an embedded web control is imho the only way to go.That way you can buy into the various web based ad networks. Anything else is going to require ... well... you to source the ads yourself.
You need to explain what is disallowed about app embeded web controls?

Comment: I have seen various applications imbed google ads in embedded browser controls - why is this 'not allowed'? Even if the advertising agents forbid it there is no obvious technical way to enforce this rule anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Although I hate these,) one option for you might be to bundle toolbars?  For example, InstallShield 2009 allows you to bundle the Yahoo! toolbar with your app's installer.  You join the Acresso Value-Added Services program and get paid everytime the toolbar is used.

Comment: I'd really rather not do that because I personally get mad when things I install have these types of things. I'm more aiming for advertisements what would be shown in a sidebar of my application.