# Ads inside a Windows application. Suggest an ad network, please

Tags: windows, ads, adsense

I'm going to place an unobtrusive ad blocks inside our Windows application.
I want the ads to look like Google AdSense text blocks.
But, unfortunately, Google AdSense policy does not allow to use ads in Windows application.

Do you know a similar ad networks that allow to place ads in computer programs?
The app is primary targeted for the US market.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed advertisements in a windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387098/embed-advertisements-in-a-windows-application)

Answer (score 2):

Tweetie (http://www.atebits.com/tweetie-mac/) uses pretty tasteful in-line ads from Fusion ads (http://fusionads.net/).  While that's a mac program, I'm sure they can be used with Windows as well.

Edit: Nevermind, looks like the Fusion network is invite-only, so it's not really a drop-in solution.  If this is a top-quality app though, you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you can do is integrate a webbrowser component in your Windows software, such as HtmlLite,

http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/delphikylix/213237/213263/re-html-viewer-in-delphi/

And let the webbrowser point to an Internet advertiser that is not Google AdSense, such as AdBrite,

http://www.associateprograms.com/articles/208/1/Adsense-Competitors-and-Alternatives/

Make sure their license allows integration in software. (I don't see why they would forbid that, after all it's just a piece of browser integrated in your software -- extra clicks, different source)